# Iterating through a list and storing results

Tags: python

I have a very simple script that looks as such:

```
from instagramy import InstagramUser

user = InstagramUser("shanutxo")
```

If you run this, it should return a response that looks as follows:

> ⚡️S H A N U T  A N A U T⚡️ (shanutxo) ->  life, style,
> empowerment + entrepreneurship via real estate + more.➕

But the way I need it to work, the script is iterating through multiple usernames that would plug into `InstagramUser("")`. It would then capture the output, store in a dataframe, and move on to the next name in the list. I have attempted to try something like:

```
import pandas as pd
from instagramy import InstagramUser

users = [['hannahkshepherd'],['sydneyhopeee'],['shanutxo'],['sunshinejilll']]
users_df = pd.DataFrame(users, columns=['usernames'])

ser = users_df.apply(InstagramUsers, axis=1, raw=True)
pd.concat([users_df, pd.DataFrame(ser, columns="bio")], axis=1)
```

But it gives me the error: `NameError: name 'InstagramUsers' is not defined`

**From Alexander's answer, I try:**

```
import pandas as pd
from instagramy import InstagramUser

users = ['calvinharris','beyonce','adele']

users_df = pd.DataFrame(users, columns=['username'])

print(users_df)

ser = users_df['username'].apply(InstagramUser)
print(ser)

test = pd.concat([users_df, pd.DataFrame(ser,columns=["bio"])], axis=1)
```

This returns a response that looks like:

[image]

But it's not capturing the response text (For example, the response for beyonce should be stored as something like "CUFF IT ㅤ season")

Comment: try it again now

Comment: You imported `InstagramUser` (singular) and used `InstagramUsers` (plural)... Presumably they should match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your previous example... you could try something like this.
This worked for me

```
users = ['calvinharris','beyonce','adele']

users_df = pd.DataFrame(users, columns=['username'])

print(users_df)

ser = users_df['username'].apply(InstagramUser)
print(ser)

pd.concat([users_df, pd.DataFrame(ser,columns=["bio"])], axis=1))
```

This is the output I get from the `print(ser)` statement

```
0    Calvin Harris (calvinharris) -> Funk Wav Bounc...
1               Beyoncé (beyonce) -> CUFF IT ㅤ season
2                                    Adele (adele) ->
```

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my answer with your response, but I keep getting an error when I run the line `ser = users_df['usernames'].apply(InstagramUser, axis=1, raw=True)` Did you run it successfully with that exact code?

Comment: Hi Alexander, I reran it, and while it works, it's not actually returning anything other than `NaN` in bio. What if I just want it to store the text response for each? It doesn't need to be split into bio or anything

Comment: Please check the edit I made. BTW I really appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Just curious, when you try running this again, does it still work? It was working earlier (minus the requested changes I asked about) but not it seems to be giving me issues

Comment: @wizkids121  see the update to my answer

Comment: @wizkids121  This api kicks bans you after a few attempts if you do not provide an instagram session id

Comment: Just curious have you been able to get that to work with the session ID and what would that look like in the script (if you were able to get it to work)? I found the ID and plugged in `session_id = "2897711656%3ADqZ1bLfkySXmum%3A12%3AAYdOIZ19-Z7uFoqbCTj4pGoJ41z5Zo6Db_yfQEMRhw"` but it won't run.

Comment: @wizkids121  No clue i dont have an instagram and this api doesn't really seem to make much sense plus it was recently archived and no longer being maintained so there are probably some issues with it